# oracle with clause error in adodb

Tags: oracle, adodb

I am not able to use the with clause in oracle adodb connection. I have tried both wrapping the qry is a select * from (myquery) and adding a , before my with clause. All create errors.

Here is the query

```
`WITH TEMPa AS (select _nbr, sum(ending) as Cost from t1 group by _nbr),
TEMPB AS (select _nbr, cost,entity
from t2
where end_tms is null and sale_date is null and entity = 110)
SELECT

TEMPA._nbr
,TEMPA.cost
,TEMPb._nbr
,TEMPB._cost
,tempb.entity
,(tempb._cost - tempa.cost) as Difference

FROM TEMPA, TEMPB
WHERE TEMPA._nbr = TEMPB._nbr(+)
and  tempa.cost <> tempb.cost`
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: could you compile this as a stored procedure with params and then call the stored procedure from adodb?

Comment: I was thinking about using a stored procedure, but other queries that follow a similar format will still need to be used. The error is < Run-time error  '3704': Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Comment: sounds like you connection may have closed

Comment: Is that that because it timed out? The query does not pull back a large dataset so that really wouldn't make sense. I have pulled much larger datasets out, however, they do not use a with statement